# Error with symfony/translate v5.3.8 and Laravel 8.0

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Since today I started getting errors in the pipeline of one of my projects.

```
Generating optimized autoload files
Class Symfony\Component\Translation\Reader\TranslationReader located in ./vendor/symfony/translation/TranslationReader.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Symfony\Component\Translation\Tests\Writer\TranslationWriterTest located in ./vendor/symfony/translation/TranslationWriterTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Symfony\Component\Translation\Tests\Catalogue\MergeOperationTest located in ./vendor/symfony/translation/MergeOperationTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Symfony\Component\Translation\Tests\DataCollector\TranslationDataCollectorTest located in ./vendor/symfony/translation/TranslationDataCollectorTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Symfony\Component\Translation\Dumper\YamlFileDumper located in ./vendor/symfony/translation/YamlFileDumper.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Symfony\Component\Translation\DependencyInjection\TranslatorPathsPass located in ./vendor/symfony/translation/TranslatorPathsPass.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Symfony\Component\Translation\Tests\DependencyInjection\TranslationPathsPassTest located in ./vendor/symfony/translation/DependencyInjection/TranslationPathsPassTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Symfony\Component\Translation\Tests\DependencyInjection\TranslationDumperPassTest located in ./vendor/symfony/translation/DependencyInjection/TranslationDumperPassTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Symfony\Component\Translation\Tests\DependencyInjection\fixtures\ServiceProperties located in ./vendor/symfony/translation/DependencyInjection/fixtures/ServiceProperties.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Symfony\Component\Translation\Tests\DependencyInjection\fixtures\ServiceArguments located in ./vendor/symfony/translation/DependencyInjection/fixtures/ServiceArguments.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Symfony\Component\Translation\Tests\DependencyInjection\fixtures\ServiceSubscriber located in ./vendor/symfony/translation/DependencyInjection/fixtures/ServiceSubscriber.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Symfony\Component\Translation\Tests\DependencyInjection\fixtures\ControllerArguments located in ./vendor/symfony/translation/DependencyInjection/fixtures/ControllerArguments.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Symfony\Component\Translation\Tests\DependencyInjection\fixtures\ServiceMethodCalls located in ./vendor/symfony/translation/DependencyInjection/fixtures/ServiceMethodCalls.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Symfony\Component\Translation\Tests\DependencyInjection\TranslatorPassTest located in ./vendor/symfony/translation/DependencyInjection/TranslatorPassTest.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Symfony\Component\Translation\Tests\DependencyInjection\TranslationExtractorPassTest located in ./vendor/symfony/translation/DependencyInjection/Transl....
```

Same happens on the local environment. The pipeline was still working at around 10 GMT today 28-09-2021. It appears that the issue has just made available.

To temporary fix the issue I roll back the symfony/translate to v5.3.4 in my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3",
        "asantibanez/livewire-calendar": "^2.1",
        "baltpeter/internetmarke-php": "^0.5.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.5",
        "bkwld/cloner": "^3.9",
        "ddeboer/imap": "^1.10",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "ijin82/flysystem-webdav": "^1.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.0",
        "laravel/helpers": "^1.4",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.0",
        "livewire-ui/modal": "^1.0",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.5",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.1",
        "soundasleep/html2text": "^1.1",
        "spatie/calendar-links": "^1.6",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^4.0",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^9.4",
        "zanysoft/laravel-zip": "^1.0",
        "symfony/translation": "5.3.4"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.6",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "kitloong/laravel-migrations-generator": "^4.5",
        "laravel/dusk": "^6.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0" 
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["app/Helpers/helpers.php"],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there a fix on it's way? Is there an error in my composer.json that may cause this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating new laravel project via composer fails with error class ArrayLoader not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69359382/creating-new-laravel-project-via-composer-fails-with-error-class-arrayloader-not)

Comment: Yes, but I was the one answering that question :-) and the temporary solution is also in my question :-)

Comment: Great, if you answered **that** question, this one is indeed a duplicate! :)

Comment: Note that in my answer on that question I offer a more complete fix, that does not need you to change your  `composer.json` when 4.3.9 is released (which should be like... right now).

Comment: By the time I composed my question they all popped up at the same time :-)

Comment: Indeed. we can expect a lot of users with the same issue. By closing this one as a duplicate to that one, we can help other users reach the solutions quicker. :)

Answer (score -1):

Can confirm this:

`Symfony\Component\Translation\` namespace seems to be main culprit